# How to create domain ontology

Tags: jena, ontology

I want to create a domain ontology model in owl or rdf format and then to parsing using jena toolkit ,i dont idea as to how to create it is there any tool or software for creating ontology??please help with the sum idea towards my approach

Answer (score 2):

Tools for creating OWL ontologies include the following:

- [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/)
- [TopQuadrant](http://www.topquadrant.com/products/TB_Composer.html)

To then work with an ontology in Jena use:

```
ModelFactory.createOntologyModel().read("http://uri-to-OWL-resource");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a look at [Neologism](http://neologism.deri.ie/). See also this ["List of Ontology Modeling Tools"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516091433/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/3316/list-of-ontology-modeling-tools)